# Order a database by a field value, and then update each row with its order number

Tags: mysql, sql

cant think of the best way to do this.

So (example):

I have a table with 10 rows. In this table there is a column called 'Points'. Each row has a value for the points table. This so far works fine.

I now want to have a column called 'Ranking'. The aim is to somehow order all of the rows in that table by the points field, and then update each rows 'Ranking' field with its order number / ranking created by ordering the rows by the points value.

So rows get ordered by the points Ascending, then i update the rows with 1 - 10 depending on their rank.

How do i go about doing this?

I already use a Cron job to update the points field so was going to include it in with this.

Thanks, Craig.

Example of how i would be ordering the rows:

```
SELECT * FROM blogs ORDER BY points ASC

Foreach row:

UDPATE blogs SET ranking  = ranking WHERE blogid = blogID
```

Thanks, P.S. Thats not the actual queries, just plain English explanation of how imagine this working.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this does what you want:

```
update blogs cross join
       (select @rn := 0) vars
    set ranking = (@rn := @rn + 1)
    order by points;
```

It uses variables and `order by` to do the ordering inside the `update`.

EDIT:

You can set the variable before the `update` as well:

```
set @rn := 0;

update blogs 
    set ranking = (@rn := @rn + 1)
    order by points;
```

Comment: @jonlink . . . That is a very vague comment that is not particularly helpful.

Comment: Sorry, but have you tested out the code? The syntax is not valid. Didn't bother trying to sort it out, but I'd guess it's the semi-colon before the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: First one still doesn't work in MySQL: `Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY`. The second one works now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered rank in sql?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx

I would imagine something similar

```
SELECT name, points
,RANK() OVER 
(PARTITION BY point ORDER BY points) AS Rank
FROM table
ORDER BY points
```

you can perhaps store this in a temp table, and update the values based on the rank numbers.
However, you might have to add logic if you don't want ties to show up as the same number.